# Why "gnome-screensaver-command -q > test.txt" do not output to file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gnome

In short, I am looking for the explanation why the output of the command does not reach the file. And if I do something wrong here, how do I do it right so the output would reach the file?

The command:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q > test.txt
```

TL;TR

At first, the short story, the point of mine was to find a way for the bash script to tell if someone is working on the computer (the screen is unlocked) or not (the screen is locked). And it seems I have found the command (`gnome-screensaver-command -q`) for that, maybe, not sure yet as I cannot really check the locked/unlocked stages with the script..

If I run the command `gnome-screensaver-command -q` in the terminal screen itself then I get the output back as expected. The output suggests me I am on the right path with the command:

```
** Message: 00:06:00.049: Screensaver is not running!
```

If I run the same code in the script and output the result to the variable `IS_SCREEN_LOCKED=$(gnome-screensaver-command -q)` then I get nothing back.. I mean, the value of `$IS_SCREEN_LOCKED` variable is empty.

If I run `gnome-screensaver-command -q > test.txt` in the terminal then `** Message: 00:06:00.049: Screensaver is not running!` reaches the screen and nothing reaches the file... Which tells me the redirect itself works quite ok (because the file is created), just the command is somehow different... May someone explain what's the trick with the output here?

I suspect it is some kind of "different type of stream".. Is there a stream, not sure if that is the good word for it, called "a query" as `man` states `-q - Query the state of the screensaver`?... Not sure what's the matter with the command directing the output to the file here.

**System details:**

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
- GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- gnome-screensaver-command 3.6.1

Comment: First, do you know that line is written to stdout, and not to stderr or the TTY? Second, do you know if it checks `isatty()` to set log levels?

Comment: More importantly: Are you sure that `gnome-screensaver-command -q` isn't communicating a result to you via exit status? If it's behaving like a good UNIX command designed for scripted invocation, you shouldn't read to read its output at all, but can just check `$?`, or (even better!) use `if gnome-screensaver-command -q; then echo "returned true"; else "returned falsey value $?"; fi`, putting your own logic in place of the `echo`s.

Comment: ...to be clear: Only _output_ is supposed to be written to stdout; anything that's diagnostic in nature (logging, errors, prompts, etc) is expected to go to stderr instead, thus for redirection with `2>` instead of `>`.

Comment: It seems the solution proposed by @CharlesDuffy and @Barmar works.. So it seems it is stderr, not stdout.. Have not expecting this one, now I know.  Thanks! Anyway, what about using `&>`, not `2>` in such situation? Does that make any sense? Seems to be better in this particular case as I wont all the information. However, it seems stdout is never with the content anyways.. Is that normal behaviour of the command to put nothing into stdout?

Comment: `&>` is a bashism -- it works if you know for sure that your shell will always be bash, but if you want to redirect both streams in a way that's compatible with all `/bin/sh` implementations, use `>target 2>&1` instead of `&>target`.

Comment: ...and it's normal for a command to not write anything to stdout _if_ that command isn't defined to output something; that's a read-the-individual-command's-documentation type determination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be writing to stderr instead of stdout. So redirect fd 2 rather than fd 1.

```
gnome-screensaver-command -q 2> test.txt
```